# Jquerymobile input mask?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I need an input mask for numerics, like "9999.99"  - or "9999.9"  . I know there are plugins for jquery in general - question is: Has anybody used one with jquerymobile? Thanks gang!

Answer (score 2):

this plugin seems nice on desktop, but for some reasons it has some problems on mobile devices (tested on android 2.3.3).
2 problems I had :

- with $('#someInput').mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"."});
  when I type 12345678, I obtain 12/45/7863 (some problems when placing the '/'s)
- when I try to give a value (calculated before but editable) it put the '../../....' in place when I focus the input.

Do someone have a workaround or a more mobile device friendly mask plugin?

Edit: After a lot of tries and failures, it seems the problem is not in the masked input plugin (which is not realy a news as it works perfectly on desktops and Ios) but it's the way android manage the modification of the value of a focus input. 
When you add a character, it display it well but remember where the cursor was and do not move it so when you type afterward it seem's it go back before the adding.

I tried to do the trick by adding a setrange but it seems to don't account the added characters. Out of ideas I did it by filtering input on keypress, spacing the characters in the input and putting an image of /  / in the background.

I'm still open to anything which could be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There's awsome plugin to use in jquery in http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
It work awsome when used in pc. But when i try on opera mobile emulator. It messed up.

Answer (score 0):

[This jsFiddle link working with phone](http://jsfiddle.net/jNkZM/24/)

The HTML is:

```
<form id="contact_info_form">   
    Cell Phone: <br/>
    <input type="text" value="" class="input-phone" name="Q3" id="Q3" />      
</form>​
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $(".input-phone").mask("(999)-999-9999");    
});​
```

Comment: Could you also add your code here, so people don't need to visit the jsfiddle to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have developed simple and easy input mask on input field to US phone format [**jquery-input-mask-phone-number**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number)

Just Add [**jquery-input-mask-phone-number**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number) plugin and call usPhoneFormat Function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourphone').usPhoneFormat({
        format: 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
    });   
});
```

Demo Example  https://jsfiddle.net/1kbat1nb/

NPM URL https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number

GitHub  URL https://github.com/rajaramtt/jquery-input-mask-phone-number